# Select part of column via regex in a MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table with e-mailaddresses, which are all like redir.`IDENTIFIER`@redirthis.url

How can I run a query which **only** selects the `identifier`?

Table `emails`

```
+----+--------------------------------+
| id | email                          |
+----+--------------------------------+
|  1 | redir.A73283@redirthis.url     |
|  2 | redir.XAAX83@redirthis.url     |
|  3 | redir.A73283F3GH@redirthis.url |
+----+--------------------------------+
```

Expected/desired result

```
+----+------------+
| id | email      |
+----+------------+
|  1 | A73283     |
|  2 | XAAX83     |
|  3 | A73283F3GH |
+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [substring_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for this if the pattern is same

```
mysql> select substring_index(substring_index('redir.A73283@redirthis.url','@',1),'.',-1);
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| substring_index(substring_index('redir.A73283@redirthis.url','@',1),'.',-1) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| A73283                                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So the query would be

```
select 
id,
substring_index(substring_index(email,'@',1),'.',-1) as email
from emails
```